# Is it possible to pass T as a DbContext into an extension method of IServiceCollection?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following:

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddCustomDbContext<T>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var typeInfo = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo();
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<T>(options =>
            {
                options
                .UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionString"],
                        sqlOptions =>
                        {
                            sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeInfo.Assembly.GetName()                                    .Name);
                            sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), null);
                        });
            });

        return services;
    }
```

I have multiple dbcontexts derived from DbContext and I would like to call this extension method with different contexts and expect it to work.

The above code results in the following error

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the
>   generic type or method
>   'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext(IServiceCollection,
>   Action, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)'.
>   There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'

Comment: You might want to add generic constraint to method `where T : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Update the OP's code with your comment as the answer. For the benefit of future searches.

Comment: @FrankNielsen I posted the answer below. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext` is a generic method but it can accept only type `T` which is `DbContext`. That means `T` should be either `DbContext` or type which is inheriting `DbContext`.

You want to pass `T` from outside method AddCustomDbContext that means you need to make sure that `AddCustomDbContext` method also accepts `T` which is `DbContext` or inherited from `DbContext`.

To achieve this you need to use generic constraint. Using generic constraint you can put a constraint for what types can be used as `T` in generic method, class or event.

You need to change the method signature as following so that it will accept only `T` which is inheriting from `DbContext`.

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddCustomDbContext<T>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) 
    where T : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
 {
     //rest of the code remains same.
 }
```

I hope this will help to solve your issue.